# Joomla CSS not rendering on IE or Firefox

Tags: css, joomla

Just had a frustrating couple of hours and I figured I'd haul out the big guns and ask the intertubes.

I have a Joomla site with a 3rd party template that doesn't seem to be rendering CSS in IE8, IE9 or Firefox, however Opera, Chrome and Safari are all reading it like a boss.

Site is: http://www.quizzically.co.uk

Theme is: http://joomlathemes.co/free-orange-template-for-joomla-2.5/

The internet is abuzz with questions from upwards of four years ago with this issue, but I'm not finding anything recent. The old issues are all very personal to the sites that they happened on as well so no love on the answers I did find.

My gut feeling is that something that directs to the CSS is not being picked up or is being ignored by Firefox and IE. I don't know what this is or how to begin looking so any help that can be offered would be ecstatically accepted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 39 of styles.css has an incorrectly coded background style:

```
#header-w {position:relative;  background:"fff }
```

The " should be a # for the color.

IE and Firefox are using stricter standards than the others, so break once there's an error.

Once that's corrected, the rest of the styles will load.

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant. How did you arrive at this? Is there some kind of CSS validator for different browsers that I should have been using?

Comment: I used firebug in Firefox initially to inspect the code and see what the CSS was doing, then the Inspect Element tool in Chrome to compare the styles.

Once they looked different, I copied the styles.css into Dreamweaver which then syntax highlights the CSS code and so the error became obvious. There's many other syntax highlighters for CSS out there for various OS.